# Is there a way to collect all the URLs for Yelp pages for a specific franchise in a city using Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, yelp

I'd like to create a list of all the URLs of Yelp pages for a franchise in a given city using Python and BeautifulSoup. I have a code that can then run through this list and scrape reviews. However, I need to define a function to collect the URLs first.

I'm expecting the output to be a list of of URLs ['url1', 'url2', etc...] but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried till now?

Comment: Do you have any code to share?  If not, check out some of these posts for ideas:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+BeautifulSoup